# Can't install web3

Tags: web3js

I am having a hard time installing web3 js via npm.
I am on Windows 10 PRO and I have the Windows build tools installed. (These build tools are required to compile the infamouse native packages).

Calling `npm install web3 --save` results in this error. I do not know which parts of the stack trace are most relevant, so I am pasting the full stack trace. Some of the warnings are in Czech language, it says something in the sense of "warning D9027: Source file definition ignored, blablabla path to node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj"

I have also tried to install scrypt separately, and I have received the same error.

```
C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web>npm install scrypt

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
Probíhá postupné sestavování projektů v tomto řešení. Pokud chcete povolit paralelní sestavování, zadejte přepínač /m.
  Copying scrypt/win/include/config.h to scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/config.h
  Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  Vytvß°Ý se kˇd.
  All 1 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
  Vytvß°enÝ kˇdu se dokonŔilo.
  copied_files.vcxproj -> C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\\copied_files.node
  memlimit.c
  keyderivation.c
  pickparams.c
  hash.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  scrypt_wrapper.vcxproj -> C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\\scrypt_wrapper.lib
  crypto_scrypt.c
  crypto_scrypt_smix.c
  warnp.c
  sha256.c
  insecure_memzero.c
  scryptenc_cpuperf.c
  mman.c
  gettimeofday.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  scrypt_lib.vcxproj -> C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\\scrypt_lib.lib
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru Invalid, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor Invalid se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru macro, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor macro se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru definition., předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor definition. se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru Invalid, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru Invalid, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru Invalid, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor Invalid se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru Invalid, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor Invalid se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor Invalid se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru macro, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor Invalid se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru macro, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru macro, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor macro se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru macro, předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor macro se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor macro se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru definition., předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor macro se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru definition., předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru definition., předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor definition. se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9024: Nerozpoznaný typ zdrojového souboru definition., předpokládá se soubor objektu. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor definition. se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor definition. se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
cl : příkazový řádek warning D9027: Zdrojový soubor definition. se ignoroval. [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Nejde otevřít soubor zdroj: ..\nan /I..\src\util /I..\src\scryptwrapper\inc /I..\src\node-boilerplate\inc /Z7 /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /MP /Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy /GL /D NODE_GYP_M
ODULE_NAME=scrypt /D USING_UV_SHARED=1 /D USING_V8_SHARED=1 /D V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1 /D WIN32 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 /D BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION /D _WINDLL /G
F /Gm- /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR- /FoRelease\obj\scrypt\ /FdRelease\obj\scrypt\vc141.pdb /Gd /TP /wd4506 /wd4351 /wd4355 /wd4800 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4244 /wd4267 /FC /errorReport:
queue /EHsc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_common.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_params_async.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_params_sync.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_kdf_async.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\sc
rypt_kdf_sync.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_kdf-verify_sync.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_kdf-verify_async.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_hash_sync.cc ..\src\node-boilerplate\scrypt_hash_async.cc ..\scrypt
_node.cc C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.cc: No such file or directory [C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v10.13.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\src\topmonks\xixoio-web\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-14T12_59_51_670Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
npm install web3 --save
```

from https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1066

Comment: Thank you, I know this recommended approach but it does not reliably works on Windows. The very first line is often problematic. The installation may hang, crash etc. It is such a pain

Comment: But I have found a workaround: Create a Docker image based on ubuntu, and install it all there.

Comment: so why not ditch windows and switch to linux ?

Comment: hehe, already tried that. But I had bad luck with Ubuntu.

Comment: there's more to linux than just ubuntu. During human history people have paid a big price for freedom, independence. This is what Linux offers you and you have to pay a small price for this independence and get out of your comfort zone